# Salvaging inaccessible MySQL db without InnoDB log files

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

In the past few weeks, I have been playing with the configuration of our test MySQL server, **without** first making a `mysqldump` of applications running on it. Aim was to increase performance and enable `lowercase_names`. I have tried to tweak InnoDB log file size, for which I had to delete (say, rename) InnoDB log files in order for them to be recreated. Eventually, I restored old log files and commented all InnoDB log file options, leaving the `lowercase_names=1` option in Linux.

**Today** I discovered that the oldest application's DB is inaccessible. While `SHOW TABLES;` reports all tables, but doing `SELECT * FROM TABLE` says `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'TABLE' doesn't exist`.

- I still have the original `ibdata1` file, which I have never backed up
- I have the backup of `ib_logfile[01]` files
- I have tried setting `innodb_force_recovery` up to 6 but I still get the same error

I already dumped all other working DBs.

### How can I salvage the last one with the given files?

Answer (score 1):

It was not a problem with InnoDB logfiles or whatever.

When I tweaked the DB configuration my goal was to **enable** `lowercase_names` because one of our applications had [hardcoded queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633938/using-case-insensitive-identifiers-in-mysql-at-session-level). This ultimately broke querying the DB I'm trying to salvage.

You can never recover a DB created and populated with different name casing. So the solution was to temporarily comment `lowercase_names`, **dump** and resume recovery from that.

Comment: This may fall in the "cannot validate new answers" (see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4192/should-i-delete-my-own-question-if-no-new-answer-can-be-validated) but since this explains a problem that may occur to others in the future, I'm in doubt if to delete or not